# NestJS: Graphql Resolver query doesn't inject complex types, its empty

Tags: nestjs

Can anyone help ?  I have a resolver query and I am passing in 3 arguments, the simple types (number) work but the complex doesn't, its just an empty object.

If I implement IQuery (graphql creates this) then everything works BUT then i can't add @Context and it says I am not implementin the interface.

Really lost, maybe I am doing something wrong ?

Here is my Resolve + Query

```
@Resolver()
export class MyResolver {

  @Query("testme")
  testme(
    @Context() context: any,
    @Args("number1") number1: number,
    @Args("number2") number2: number,
    @Args({ name: "paginationInput", type: () => MyPaginationInput }) paginationInput: MyPaginationInput
  ) {
```

and my simple query that I am passing down

```
{
    testme(number1:1, number2: 1, paginationInput: {page:1, pageSize:10})
}
```

The above i have tried @Args without passing in the type and just passing in the name of the property but still nothing. It just injects me an empty object, page and pageSize are empty - they dont even exist.

and here is the graphql query and additional types

```
type Query {
  testme(number1: Int, number2: Int, paginationInput: PaginationInput): Boolean
}


input PaginationInput {
    page: Int
    pageSize: Int
}
```

and here is my class in typescript

```
export class MyPaginationInput {
  page?: number
  pageSize?: number
}
```

Thanks in advance

**Update**

If I change the signature to the following then it works

```
  testme(obj: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) {
```

args complains paginationInput with page and pageSize populated.

Comment: Oh I should mentioned its Schema First not Code First.

Comment: Are you able to share a github repo or CodeSandbox that reproduces where you're currently stuck?